# MongoTemplate Aggregation to count number of distinct product id

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-jpa, aggregation-framework

I am trying to get count of distinct product_id through aggregation in springData.

document looks something like this

```
{
   {'product_id':1,
    'name' : hell
   }
   {
     'product_id':1,
     'name' : bajaj
   }
   {
     'product_id':2,
     'name':husky
   }
}
```

i want to return a variable count of long type. 
This is the code that i tried to work on but i am getting error saying cannot convert list<> to long .

```
  Aggregation aggregation=newAggregation(match(criteria),group(FieldNames.PRODUCT_ID).count().as("count"),project("count"));

  return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation,PriceMappedProduct.COLLECTION_NAME,long.class).getMappedResult();
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, you may do it like this to get count:

**Option 1:**

```
List<BasicDBObject> count = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation,PristinePriceMappedProduct.COLLECTION_NAME,BasicDBObject.class).getMappedResult();

// mongoTemplate.aggregate is returning list hence the error.

if(count!=null){
    return count.size();
} else{
    return 0;
}
```

**Option 2: (one liner)**

```
return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation,PristinePriceMappedProduct.COLLECTION_NAME,BasicDBObject.class).getMappedResult();
// in this case make sure this function's return type is Integer or Long not int or long
```

**NOTE:** 
 in this case, make sure the function's return type is `Integer` or `Long` not `int` or `long` as `int` and `long` are primitive data types and they do not contain `null`. However, in case, there is no data, the aggregation logic might return `null` hence the use of Long or Integer (object could be null)

Comment: Hey Thanks For The Reply , That was the right answer :-D :-D . if getting count of  distinct id can be optimised any further ?